# unstacking shift data (start and end time) into hourly data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as follows which shows when a person started a shift, ended a shift, the amount of hours and the date worked.

```
Business_Date   Number PayTimeStart PayTimeEnd          Hours
0   2019-05-24  1       2019-05-24 11:00:00 2019-05-24 12:15:00 1.250
1   2019-05-24  2       2019-05-24 12:30:00 2019-05-24 13:30:00 1.00
```

Now what I'm trying to do is break this into an hourly format, so I know how many hours were used between 11:00 - 12:00

so, in my head, for the above, I want to put the 1 hour between 11 - 12 into the bin for 11:00 and the remainder 0.25 into the next bin of 12

so I would end up with something like

```
    Business Date   Time Hour
0   2019-05-24  11:00 1
1   2019-05-24  12:00 0.75
2   2019-05-24  13:00 0.5
```

Comment: you can perform math on dates. get a date which start before 12 and end after. make a datetime object of the same date but at 12. the start time from your new object to get the amount of time before 12. subtract your new object from the end time to get the time after 12. you can load your text dates into object using: `datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-05-24 11:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: @Nullman this was my initial thoughts, to preform a sum and put the remainder into the next hour but I have no idea how to do this in code, hence my question : ) if you can show me how i'd be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One idea is working with minutes - first use list comprehension with flattening for `Series` and then grouping by `hours` with `hour`s for count by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and last divide by `60` for final hours:

```
s = pd.Series([z for x, y in zip(df['Pay Time Start'], 
                                 df['Pay Time End'] - pd.Timedelta(60, unit='s')) 
                 for z in pd.date_range(x, y, freq='Min')])

df = (s.groupby([s.dt.date.rename('Business Date'), s.dt.hour.rename('Time')])
       .size()
       .div(60)
       .reset_index(name='Hour'))
print (df)
  Business Date  Time  Hour
0    2019-05-24    11  1.00
1    2019-05-24    12  0.75
2    2019-05-24    13  0.50
```

If you need to group by a location or ID

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame([(z, w) for x, y, w in zip(df['Pay Time Start'], 
                                              df['Pay Time End'] - pd.Timedelta(60, unit='s'), 
                                              df['Location']) for z in pd.date_range(x, y, freq='Min')], 
                   columns=['Date','Location']) 

 df = (df1.groupby([df1['Date'].dt.date.rename('Business Date'), 
                       df1['Date'].dt.hour.rename('Time'), df1['Location']]) 
          .size() .div(60) .reset_index(name='Hour'))
```

Comment: Jozi you are my hero! I understand what's happening in the 2nd part of code, but in the series, are you creating a dict to workout the time?

Comment: @Datanovice - My real name, thank you. I use list comprehension for list of minutes resolution between start and end values and flattening is for avoid nested lists.

Comment: Just an additional nice to have, this isn't part of the original question, but if my df has a `location` column, how would I keep that included?

Comment: @Datanovice - Can you check `df1 = pd.DataFrame([(z, w) for x, y, w in zip(df['Pay Time Start'], df['Pay Time End'] - pd.Timedelta(60, unit='s'), df['Number']) 
                 for z in pd.date_range(x, y, freq='Min')], columns=['Date','Number'])

df = (df1.groupby([df1['Date'].dt.date.rename('Business Date'), df1['Date'].dt.hour.rename('Time'), df1['Number']])
       .size()
       .div(60)
       .reset_index(name='Hour'))`

Answer (score 2):

Another idea, similar's to @jezrael's but work with seconds for higher precision:

```
def get_series(a):
    s, e, h = a
    idx = pd.date_range(s,e, freq='6s')
    return pd.Series(h/len(idx), index=idx)

(pd.concat(map(get_series, zip(df.Pay_Time_Start,
                          df.Pay_Time_End, 
                          df.Hours)))
   .resample('H').sum()
)
```

Output:

```
2019-05-24 11:00:00    0.998668
2019-05-24 12:00:00    0.750500
2019-05-24 13:00:00    0.500832
Freq: H, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea just for your convenience (plus I like challenging questions) is using [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and then conditionally calculating the minutes:

Basically, you have two formulas for your calculations (Pseudocode):

- *Minutes in Pay Time Start*: `60 - minutes in df['Pay Time Start]`
- *Minutes in Pay Time End*: `minutes in df['Pay Time End]`

So we can use these formulas to create our new data:

First we melt our Times in one column

```
new = df.melt(id_vars=['Business Date', 'Number'], 
              value_vars=['Pay Time Start', 'Pay Time End'],
              var_name='Pay Time Name',
              value_name='Pay Time Date').sort_values('Number')

# Apply the formulas noted above
new['Minutes'] = np.where(new['Pay Time Name'].eq('Pay Time Start'), 
                          60 - new['Pay Time Date'].dt.minute, 
                          new['Pay Time Date'].dt.minute)

# Out
  Business Date  Number   Pay Time Name       Pay Time Date  Minutes
0    2019-05-24       1  Pay Time Start 2019-05-24 11:00:00       60
2    2019-05-24       1    Pay Time End 2019-05-24 12:15:00       15
1    2019-05-24       2  Pay Time Start 2019-05-24 12:30:00       30
3    2019-05-24       2    Pay Time End 2019-05-24 13:30:00       30
```

---

Now we calculate the amount of hours with `groupby`:

```
daterange = pd.date_range(df['Pay Time Start'].min(), df['Pay Time End'].max(), freq='H')

df_new = pd.DataFrame({'Date':daterange.date,
                    'Time':daterange.time}, dtype='datetime64[ns]')

df_new['Hours'] = (new.groupby(new['Pay Time Date'].dt.hour)['Minutes'].sum()/60).to_numpy()
```

**Final Output**

```
        Date      Time  Hours
0 2019-05-24  11:00:00   1.00
1 2019-05-24  12:00:00   0.75
2 2019-05-24  13:00:00   0.50
```

Comment: Thanks for this, glad I'm not the only one who found this challenging! I like this approach, it's more more dynamic (meaning I could apply this to a wide array of time data)