# unpacking time data with categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
        site    start_time  end_time    day_week    bike_repair car_repair  touring
0   a1  01/01/1901 11:00    01/01/1901 11:15    Sat_1   1   0   0
1   a2  01/01/1901 11:15    01/01/1901 11:30    Sat_1   0   0   1
2   a3  01/01/1901 11:30    01/01/1901 11:45    Sat_1   1   1   0
3   a4  01/01/1901 11:45    01/01/1901 12:00    Sat_1   1   0   0
4   a5  01/01/1901 12:00    01/01/1901 12:15    Sat_1   0   1   1
5   a6  01/01/1901 12:15    01/01/1901 12:30    Sat_1   1   1   1
6   a7  01/01/1901 12:30    01/01/1901 12:45    Sat_1   1   0   1
7   a8  01/01/1901 12:45    01/01/1901 13:00    Sat_2   0   1   0
8   a9  01/01/1901 13:00    01/01/1901 13:15    Sat_2   0   0   0
9   a10 01/01/1901 13:15    01/01/1901 13:30    Sat_2   1   1   1
10  a11 01/01/1901 13:30    01/01/1901 13:45    Sat_2   1   1   1
11  a12 01/01/1901 13:45    01/01/1901 14:00    Sat_2   1   0   1
12  a13 01/01/1901 14:00    01/01/1901 14:15    Sat_2   0   1   1
13  a14 01/01/1901 14:15    01/01/1901 14:30    Sat_2   0   1   1
```

please use `pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t')` to read the df into your editors.

1 means that I have coverage for that skill during that 15min interval and 0 means i don't.

the day_week refers to the day in the week and the week number.

now, what I want to understand is at any given time what coverage do I have. I have another dataframe which the opening and close times of my outlets which I'd like to merge onto after some wrangling.

I have melted the dataframe from this and it gives me the following

```
(pd.melt(so,id_vars=['site','start_time','end_time','day_week']
,var_name='Skill',value_name='Coverage'))

        site    start_time  end_time    day_week    Skill   Coverage
0   a1  01/01/1901 11:00    01/01/1901 11:15    Sat_1   bike_repair 1
1   a2  01/01/1901 11:15    01/01/1901 11:30    Sat_1   bike_repair 0
2   a3  01/01/1901 11:30    01/01/1901 11:45    Sat_1   bike_repair 1
3   a4  01/01/1901 11:45    01/01/1901 12:00    Sat_1   bike_repair 1
4   a5  01/01/1901 12:00    01/01/1901 12:15    Sat_1   bike_repair 0
5   a6  01/01/1901 12:15    01/01/1901 12:30    Sat_1   bike_repair 1
6   a7  01/01/1901 12:30    01/01/1901 12:45    Sat_1   bike_repair 1
7   a8  01/01/1901 12:45    01/01/1901 13:00    Sat_2   bike_repair 0
8   a9  01/01/1901 13:00    01/01/1901 13:15    Sat_2   bike_repair 0
9   a10 01/01/1901 13:15    01/01/1901 13:30    Sat_2   bike_repair 1
10  a11 01/01/1901 13:30    01/01/1901 13:45    Sat_2   bike_repair 1
```

which gets me close to what I want, I then want to use the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56341590/unstacking-shift-data-start-and-end-time-into-hourly-data) post but I'm having the following issues :

the data after melting is 6m rows with 15 unique types in the `Skill` column

after trying to adapt the answer I get a memory error, so it possible to change this to match 15min intervals and sum the coverage column ?

I'm trying to get something like

```
site    time    day_week    skill   coverage
0   a1  11:00   Sat_1   bike_repair 1
1   a1  11:15   Sat_1   bike_repair 0
2   a1  11:30   Sat_1   bike_repair 1
3   a1  11:45   Sat_1   bike_repair 1
4   a1  12:00   Sat_1   bike_repair 0
5   a1  12:15   Sat_1   bike_repair 1
```

OR

```
site    start_time  day_week    skill   Coverage
0   a1  11:01   Sat_1   bike_repair 1
1   a1  11:02   Sat_1   bike_repair 1
2   a1  11:03   Sat_1   bike_repair 1
3   a1  11:04   Sat_1   bike_repair 1
4   a1  11:05   Sat_1   bike_repair 1
5   a1  11:06   Sat_1   bike_repair 1
6   a1  11:07   Sat_1   bike_repair 1
7   a1  11:08   Sat_1   bike_repair 1
8   a1  11:09   Sat_1   bike_repair 1
9   a1  11:10   Sat_1   bike_repair 1
10  a1  11:11   Sat_1   bike_repair 1
11  a1  11:12   Sat_1   bike_repair 1
12  a1  11:13   Sat_1   bike_repair 1
13  a1  11:14   Sat_1   bike_repair 1
14  a1  11:15   Sat_1   bike_repair 0
15  a1  11:16   Sat_1   bike_repair 0
16  a1  11:17   Sat_1   bike_repair 0
17  a1  11:18   Sat_1   bike_repair 0
18  a1  11:19   Sat_1   bike_repair 0
```

Comment: Not sure if understand. Because it there are only 15 minutes intervals is possible use `df = df.groupby(['site','Skill', df['start_time'].dt.time,'day_week'])['Coverage'].sum().reset_index()` ?

Comment: Or `df = df.groupby(['site','Skill', df['start_time'].str.split().str[1],'day_week'])['Coverage'].sum().reset_index()`

Comment: @jezrael I've been testing this for a while but the numbers I get don't add up (for example I'm getting 3 where i can manually count two) I updated my question slightly

Comment: hmmm, is possible change sample data for seen, what is aggregate? Because output from melt and expected output seems same.

Comment: you are right, there was duplicate keys in my data!!!! I'm so sorry (someone gave me the data dump from alterxy!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
so['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(so['start_time'])
so['end_time'] = pd.to_datetime(so['end_time'])

df = (df.groupby(['site','Skill', df['start_time'].dt.time,'day_week'])['Coverage']
        .sum()
        .reset_index())
```

Comment: thanks as always sir, really appreciate you helping random strangers on the internet!